# After upgraded tensorflow2.1,I got "RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution."

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm new here,recently I am learning CNN with tensorflow and keras,and I am trying to run cnn model to train mnist dataset,but After I upgraded with tnesorflow 2.0 to 2.1, I got this error message:

```
 raise RuntimeError("tf.placeholder() is not compatible with "

 RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.
```

I try this code

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

and next,

```
##build input layer

with tf.compat.v1.name_scope('Input_Layer'):
x=tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float",shape=[None, 784],name="x")
x_image = tf.compat.v1.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])
```

and below is CNN model, so I can run the model successfully,but I still want to understand why....
(before I upgraded to 2.1,I can run the model,but now I need that code...)
could someone help me figure out??   Thanks..

Comment: The point of Eager Execution is to get rid of prebuilt graphs, that therefore placeholders.

Answer (score 4):

use this line in your code:
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()